# Max possible square paint brush to paint a canvas

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

There is a problem which had asked to me in a interview. Problem statement is as below:-
There is a painter and having a NxM Grid canvas. Painter has paint brush of any square size i.e of any nxn size. Painter knows which blocks of grid he need to paint and which has to be left white (Painter intent to paint a Yellow and white painting). So any block of grid shall either be yellow or white.In addition to this there are some don't care blocks which either be painted with yellow color or left white. Now, we have to propose a algorithm to minimize effort of painter and tell maximum possible nxn brush which can be used to paint the canvas.
Example:-

[Sample canvas of 8x4 Grid. Yellow color block has to paint,white color block has to left white and blue color block are don't care blocks can either be white or painted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWt2U.png)

As per above example,a maximum size of 2x2 brush can be use to successfully paint the canvas.

I propose its solution using brute force i.e check for each color and decide which will cover in max possible square brush.Interviewer didn't satisfied with this solution.
I want to ask:- 
1)what is the best way to do this problem .
2) can this be solved using Dynamic Programming concept.

Comment: first optimization which comes to my mind - start with brush size `min(gridweight, gridheight) / 2` and try to paint everything, if this brush can paint everything - increase brush size, otherwise decrease, like you do in binary search

Comment: It is enough for each yellow field to find maximal yellow-blue square containing it. Minimum size of these squares is a solution.

Comment: Please sort out `Painter intent to paint a Yellow …` and `don't care blocks which either be painted with black color or …`.

Comment: @greybeard painter going to paint with one color (i.e yellow here)... anyway thnx for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote `min(N,M)` by `A`. This problem can be solved in `O(A^2 N M Log A)` with a simple solution. Also there is a complicated solution `O(N M Log A)`.

**Important Observation**

If it's possible to color the board with `K x K` brush, then it's definitely possible to color the board with any smaller brush. Therefore we can solve the problem by binary search.

**Solution Scratch**

```
int left = 1, right = min(N, M) + 1;
while (right - left > 1) {
  int middle = (left + right) / 2;
  if (PossibleToColor(middle)) {
    left = middle;
  } else {
    right = middle;
  }
}
OutputAnswer(left);
```

**Simple Solution and Hints for Complicated Solution**

The only tricky thing that remained is how to implement `PossibleToColor(int K)`.

Simple solution just iterates over every possible position of the brush. If there is no white cell under the brush in this position, we need to paint all the cells under the brush. After all positions are checked, we need to check that every yellow cell was painted. Each call of `PossibleToColor` will run in `O(K^2NM)`, hence `O(A^2 N M Log A)` total running time.

In complicated solution you need to to build an integer matrix `NxM`. Its element is equal one if and only if the corresponding pixel of canvas is white, otherwise it is equal zero. Then you need to iterate over all brush positions and check whether we can put a brush here (you need to compute a sum on a sub-square, if it is positive, then you cannot). To do it quickly you need to use a data structure to compute a sum of numbers in a subrectangle of integer matrix in `O(1)`. It's possible to build such data structure in `O(NM)`.

Then after you find all the possible positions of the brush, you need to build one more integer matrix `NxM`. Its element is equal to one if and only if there is a brush position with upper left corner in this element, otherwise it's equal zero. Then you need to iterate over each yellow pixel and check if it will be painted by at least one possible position of the brush or not. To check that you need to compute a sum in a sub-rectangle on the described matrix. You need to do it with the same data structure.

The described data structure for integer matrix `A` is just a matrix `S`, such that

`S[i][j]` = sum of `A[p][q]` such that `1 <= p <= i`, `1 <= p <= j`

It can be computed with simple dynamic programming in `O(NM)`. When you computed it, the sum in subrectangle `i1 <= i <= i2, j1 <= j <= j2` can be computed as

`S[i2][j2] - S[i2][j1 - 1] - S[i1 - 1][j2] + S[i1 - 1][j1 - 1]`.